# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\log(e^n+e^{-n})}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Test convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {1}{\log(e^n+e^{-n})}$

**Attempt:** I have tried the integral test, the comparison test ( for which I couldn't find a suitable comparator).

However, I haven't been able to proceed much. Could anyone please give me a direction on how to proceed ahead with this problem.

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^{n}+e^{-n}< 2e^{n}$, hence
$$\frac{1}{\log(e^n+e^{-n})}>\frac{1}{n+\log 2}$$
and the series is divergent by direct comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Is someone having fun in distributing random downvotes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) . Someone's just randomly downvoted all the answers and the question too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** compare with the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You are welcome!